# Convertir un JOIN en Laravel

Tags: laravel, json

Me encuentro en un pequeño problema, logre hacer una consulta en MySQL para obtener datos de tres tablas distintas, con dichos datos deseo imprimirlos en mi página WEB, he investigado y resulta que debo utilizar JSON y Ajax para poder almacenar mis datos y poder imprimirlos dentro de mi página con un @foreach solo que por más que intento no logro convertir mi consulta en mi controlador en Laravel para que funcione, alguien me podría apoyar explicándome un poco como es que se genera la consulta.

Les dejo mi consulta

```
   select m.nombre_marca,a.nombre_producto , a.direccion_agencia, 
          c.nombre, c.email, c.telefono FROM marca m 
   INNER JOIN agencia a ON m.idmarca = a.id_marca 
   INNER JOIN contacto_agencia c ON a.idagencia = c.id_agencia;
```

Muchas gracias por su apoyo !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que puedes transformar tu consulta del siguiente modo

```
$data = \DB::table('marca AS m')
        ->select('m.nombre_marca', 'a.nombre_producto', 'a.direccion_agencia', 
                 'c.nombre', 'c.email', 'c.telefono')
        ->join('agencia AS a', 'm.idmarca', '=', 'a.id_marca')
        ->join('contacto_agencia AS c', 'a.idagencia', '=', 'c.id_agencia')
        ->get();
```

1. Los `joins()` los logras a través del método `->join()`
2. El `select()` lo hago antes de los `joins` indicando separados por comas y entre comillas cada una de las columnas deseadas

para comprobar la data que te llega, basta con que hagas

`var_dump($data);`

Demtro de la vista, lo haces

```
@foreach($data as $d)
   {{ $d->columnaNombre }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias shadow me acabas de resolver la duda y el problema que tenía, ya que no sabia como transformar mi consulta en Laravel ya que es donde estoy trabajando. Te agradezco mucho de tu apoyo y tu tiempo que me brindaste en aclararme mi problema.

Comment: no hay problema con gusto se te ayuda, cuando tengas otra duda posteala y te apoyamos @Bahamut4321  saludos y éxito